# Reference ORM (Entity) from ODM (Document, MongoDB) with ManyToMany relationship

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, mapping, doctrine-odm

I am trying to blend ODM (MongoDB) and ORM in my Symfony 2.6 with a reference to the Documentation ["Blending ORM and MongoDB ODM"](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/cookbook/blending-orm-and-mongodb-odm.html)

I have two entities, `User` and `Category`. Also I have one Document `Product`.

It's clear when blending ODM and ORM, it can be solved easily with OneToMany or ManyToOne case - on one side we define ReferenceOne link + both `field` specifing `identifier="fieldId"` and `fieldId` itself, on another side we define ReferenceMany).

My challenge is getting `$product->categories` populated with relation ManyToMany. So far, `$product->user` is getting retrieved normally, when `$product->userId` is filled. But I can't achieve the same with `$product->categories`.

Can you help me to find a solution?

```
/** 
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection $products
     * 
     * @Gedmo\ReferenceMany(type="document", class="Document\Product", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $products;
}

/** 
 * @Gedmo\Tree(type="nested")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="categories")
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection $products
     * 
     * @Gedmo\ReferenceMany(type="document", class="Document\Product", mappedBy="products")
     */
    protected $products;
}
```

and then I have a Document

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 * @MongoDB\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @Gedmo\ReferenceOne(type="entity", class="Entity\User", inversedBy="products", identifier="userId")
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Field(name="user_id", type="int")
     */
    protected $userId;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\ReferenceMany(type="entity", class="Entity\Category", mappedBy="products")
     */
    protected $categories = array();

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Collection
     */
    protected $categoryIds = array();

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function getCategories()
    {
        return $this->categories;
    }
```

}

P.S> listeners `gedmo.listener.reference` and `utils.listener.reference` do exist.

Comment: So far I had to introduce custom solution with loading categories using categoryIds array that is stored in documents. Same for persisting, I am updating Ids array on PrePersist. But still looking for an elegant solution.

Answer (score 3):

There is actual documentation for that use case provided by doctrine:

[Blending the ORM and MongoDB ODM](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/cookbook/blending-orm-and-mongodb-odm.html)

It's basically a manual implementation of doctrine's reference model. In short: You store an id ( or a list of ids) in a property that is mapped and persisted via doctrine.

Then during the load process (either via event listener or method annotations) you fetch the respective documents and store them in separate property. Then during the flush process (either via event listener or method annotations) you get the (possibly changed) objects's id(s) and put them back in your first property.

We have been using a slightly altered version of this approach in our core product for years now and it works fine, without any hiccups and very transparently.

For the more curious: It's also possible ( and harder but more convenient in the long run ) to built a custom doctrine type for that.

Comment: I haven't mentioned that in my original post, but I was actually referring to the existing documentation "Blending the ORM and MongoDB ODM". That's why I started my message with "I am trying to blend..."

I will add it to my original post. 

I am using "categoryIds" property and subscribing to events via custom EventSubscriber. But I was hoping there is another way, like it's done by Doctrine.

Comment: Well, as I mentioned, you could go the custom type route for that